# Flutter how to listen to web hook

Tags: flutter, dart, webhooks

At the moment I am making a mobile application that receives data from an API, this data provides a `post` that someone posted on a forum. I am displaying these post under a topic the user replied to.

At the moment I do a periodic Timer that re-request the data from the API every 30-60 seconds. I am not sure if this is the optimal way to do this.

```
  void enableTimer(id, slug) {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 30), (Timer timer) {
      _recentlyDeletedPost = false;
      _recentlyDeletedPostId = '';
      _future = fetchPost(id, slug);
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

I have set up a web-hook with the forum API. The only thing is that I can't find any information about this subject in the Flutter documentation on how to listen to the web-hook.

I have tried looking at different examples of the `stream` and `streamBuilder` class but no luck yet.

My understanding of webhooks is quite poor and I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: cannot you use `WebSocket` for that (provided your API have any `WebSocket` entry points)?

Comment: I agree with the comment above - what you need is a Websocket. You would need to deploy a piece of backend that will subscribe to your Webhook, and push the information through WebSocket to your flutter app. Flutter app will have a connection to WebSocket server. You can't expect the Forum API to find your mobile device - you don't know your IP or URL of your device.